# What is the best strategy for BDD testing which relies on data

Tags: tdd, integration-testing, bdd, automated-tests

What are some strategies for writing BDD tests, which can test behaviour that relies on certain data being in the system?

For example, say I was working with the following scenario:

```
Feature: Search for friend
    In order to find a friend
    As a user
    I want to search my list of friends
    And filter by 'first name'
```

How could this test ever succeed unless/until some "dummy" friends had been entered into the system?

More to the point, what "dummy" criteria would the test utilize?

---

Should I hard-code the name of a friend, assuming it to already exist in the database?

**But** what if I move my code to a new environment with a fresh database?

---

Or, should I write code to manually insert dummy data into the system prior to executing each test?

**But** this would be modifying the internal state of the application from within a test framework, which seems like a bad approach, since we're supposed to be treating the program as a black-box, and only dealing with it through an interface.

---

Or, would I create other scenarios/tests, in which the data is created using an interface of the program?

For example, 'Feature: Add a new friend to my list'. Then I could run that test, to add a user called 'Lucy', then run the 'Search for friend' tests to search for 'Lucy', which would now exist in the database.

**But**, then I'd be introducing dependencies between my scenarios, which contradicts the common advice that tests should be independently runnable.

---

Which one the best strategy? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use the Given clause in your scenario to get the system into the appropriate state for the test. The actual implementation of this would be hidden in the step definition.

If the data is going to shared across your scenarios then you could have in a background step:

```
Background:
  Given I have the following friends:
    | andy smith   |
    | andy jones   |
    | andrew brown |
```

To add these friends you could either insert records directly into the database:

```
def add_friend(name)
  Friend.create!(:name => name)
end
```

or automate the UI, e.g.:

```
def add_friend(name)
  visit '/friends/new'
  fill_in 'Name', :with => name
  click_button 'Add'
end
```

For the scenarios themselves, you would need to think of key examples to validate the behaviour, e.g.:

```
Scenario: Searching for a existing person by first name
  When I search for 'andy'
  Then I should see the friends:
    | andy smith |
    | andy jones |
  But I should not see "andrew brown"

Scenario: Searching for a non-existing person by first name
  When I search for 'peter'
  Then I should not see any friends
```

You're correct that tests should be independent, so you shouldn't rely on other scenarios to leave the database in a particular state. You will probably need some mechanism to clean-up after each test. For example, the 'database-cleaner' gem if you're using Cucumber and Rails.

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to BDD and Integration style of testing. If you use a decent ORM (NHibernate?) you can create an in-memory database before each test runs and clean it up after the test succeeds and since the db is in memory, it won't take much time comparing to running it on a real database.

You can use the pre/post test hooks to fit in the data necessary for your scenario and clean it up afterwards so that your tests can be run without depending on each other.

Comment: So then, what happened to the idea that BDD should test the system as a black-box, and not manipulate the internals? Do we just throw that idea out? Or are you saying that there's no real answer, but this is the best compromise?

Comment: Ideally all setup would be done by automating the UI, but for reasons of performance and easier test maintainability, it's often ok to just insert data directly into the database, as long as you have separate scenarios elsewhere which cover adding data using the UI.

Comment: sorry, just found out about the question...The thing is you don't have to do this the integration style. If you have abstracted your data access so that it supports in-memory data, it is often to write your test using this mechanism. The thing is even abstracting the whole ORM away is not really a good practice as you'll loose a lot of ORM specific feature and power, but at the end you can decide between the two approach.

Comment: I'd argue that by inserting data directly into the DB, you're undermining the usefulness of behaviour testing, since you're "artificially" putting your application in a particular state rather than relying on the UI to do it. A human tester using the UI for the entire end-to-end test would pick up issues such as inconsistent data or unspecified requirements. So behaviour tests should emulate this, and use the UI to drive everything, rather than fiddling with the internal state of the application to "force" things to work.

Comment: The authors of The RSpec Book write: "Leveraging the DMA (direct model access) style for Givens can provide convenience, simplicity and speed without reducing confidence. We use this approach when the actions required to get to a specific database state have already been exercised through the full Rails stack in their own Simulated Browser scenarios."